# ng-required does not work as expected, only works when variable is displayed in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a problem when using ng-required in my controller, I have initialize `vm.jobRequired` as `true` when I first render the page.

```
    <input-field class="col m6 s12">
        <select class="select-overflow" custom-material-select ng-model="vm.details.ti_jo_id" ng-disabled="!vm.jobs.length" ng-change="vm.getJoblinesByJobId(true)" ng-required="vm.jobRequired">
            <option value="">* Select Job</option>
            <option value="{{job.id}}" ng-repeat="job in vm.jobs" ng-selected="{{ vm.details.ti_jo_id == job.id }}">{{job.jo_name}}</option>
        </select>
    </input-field>
```

My problem is when I change `vm.jobRequired` as `false` my select dropdown is still required even if it should not.

I would like to point that I have another select dropdown, who has a `ng-change` to call `checkSelectedCostcode` method I made to change `vm.jobRequired`
My code for changing `vm.jobRequired`:

```
function checkSelectedCostcode ( id ) {
    var selectedCostcode = _.find( vm.allcostcodes, function ( costcode ) {
        return costcode.cc_id === id;
    } );

    if ( selectedCostcode.cc_tiejob_flag === '0' ) {
        vm.jobRequired = false;
        return;
    }
    vm.jobRequired = true;
}
```

The weird thing is this code only works if I display vm.jobRequired in my html file.

```
<input-field class="col m6 s12">
    <select class="select-overflow" custom-material-select ng-model="vm.details.ti_jo_id" ng-disabled="!vm.jobs.length" ng-change="vm.getJoblinesByJobId(true)" ng-required="vm.jobRequired">
        <option value="">* Select Job{{vm.jobRequired}}</option>
        <option value="{{job.id}}" ng-repeat="job in vm.jobs" ng-selected="{{ vm.details.ti_jo_id == job.id }}">{{job.jo_name}}</option>
    </select>
</input-field>
```

If you can see here I displayed `vm.jobRequired` near my "Select Job" text, my code now works as expected. If it's not displayed, it does not.

Does anybody know why this is happening? I'm kind of guessing that the two-way data binding that I expect should work is not working in this case. I do not know how let this work without calling `vm.jobRequired`

Comment: provide a plnkr with your code

Comment: Have you tried with `$scope.$apply()` after you change `vm.jobRequired`?

Comment: @Arg0n it throws an error `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress` I tried placing it inside my checkSelectedCostcode method

Comment: Okay. Then as @NitsanBaleli said, provide plnkr/JSFiddle with your code for us to test.